# Configure NoseGAE to update index.yaml like development server

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, nosetests

Is it possible to configure or modify the NoseGAE plugin to automatically update index.yaml when queries are run in tests (like the development server does)? I have 100% test coverage so this would be quite useful.

Has anybody had any luck with such a testing suite setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my Nose plugin for this, called [nose-gae-index](http://github.com/jkrebs/nose-gae-index). It uses the internal IndexYamlUpdater class from the SDK.

There is no need to have it enabled all the time. I use it before deployment and to inspect changes to index configuration caused by new commits.

Remember not to use queries that require indexes in the tests themselves, or they will be added to the configuration file as well!